# Update SQL Server por medio de Visual Studio ASP.NET web forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, visual-studio

Estoy intentando hacer un `update` en una DB, pero no me esta realizando los cambios dicho comando. Cuando lo hago en la query directo de *SQL server* si funciona, pero cuando lo hago desde mi aplicación no hace el *update*.

Esta es la query en SQL Server:

```
update cliente set telefono = '864346', cedula = '8826537',
nombre = 'Lucho', direccion = 'Cll 60 # 15 - 45'
where cedula = '123456789' 
and nombre = 'Luis Ocampo'
and telefono = '3116085275'
and direccion = 'sddferr';
```

Esta es el código desde Visual Studio:

```
string s = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadenaconexion1"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(s);
            conexion.Open();
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("update cliente set " + 
                                 "cedula = '" + ccliente.Text + "', nombre = '" +
                                 ncliente.Text + "', telefono = '" + ctelefono.Text +
                                 "', direccion = '" + cdireccion.Text + "' where cedula = '" + 
                                 ccliente.Text + "' and nombre = '" +
                                 ncliente.Text + "' and telefono = '" + 
                                 ctelefono.Text + "' and direccion = '" + 
                                 cdireccion.Text + "'", conexion);

            ccliente.Text = string.Empty;
            ncliente.Text = string.Empty;
            ctelefono.Text = string.Empty;
            cdireccion.Text = string.Empty;

            msgerror.Text = "Información actualizada con exito";

            conexion.Close();
```

No se si estaré *comiendome* algo, o si entendí mal el proceso que se tiene que hacer con los `Texbox` para actualizar la info.

Quedo atento, por favor, ojala puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema principal es que estás asignando query al comando, pero no lo envías nunca al motor de base de datos. En otras palabras no ejecutas el comando.

Para enviar el UPDATE, ejecuta el método ExecuteNonQuery, por ejemplo:

```
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

Una vez aclarado esto. Me voy a tomar el atrevimiento de dejarte algunos **consejos**. Pueden haber otros modos de hacerlo que difieran del mio. Queda en vos investigar cual es el mas adecuado y se acomoda a tu proyecto.

- Al hacer un UPDATE de un registro SIEMPRE lo debes hacer por el ID
  que le corresponde. Nunca utilizando los valores actuales como
  condiciones.
- Estas usando para el WHERE los mismo valores que quieres asignar.
  Aquí mas que un consejo, remarco un error.
- Debes evitar usar la concatenación en las consultas ya que te pueden
  ocasionar muchos  inconvenientes. Para eso puedes utilizar por
  ejemplo [SqlParameterCollection](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2).
  En este caso no estas trabajando con fechas ni datos complejos, pero
  en un futuro se te hará indispensable. Aparte de que te expones a 
  [inyección de
  SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Existen
  otros métodos, puedes investigar cual se adapta mejor a tu uso.
- Siempre hacer las consultas dentro de un Using. Algo así:

---

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
  "Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind"))
{
    connection.Open();      
    // Pool A is created.
}
```

---

***¿Por qué usar " using" en el código?***

En C # hay algunos objetos que utilizan los recursos del sistema. Los cuales deben eliminarse, cerrarse, vaciarse y desecharse, etc. En C # puede escribir el código para Crear una nueva instancia en el recurso, usarlo, cerrarlo, vaciarlo, desecharlo. O, por otro lado, simplemente puede usar este usingbloque de declaración en el que el objeto creado se cierra, se vacía y se desecha y los recursos pueden ser utilizados de nuevo por otros procesos. Esto asegura que el marco tomará las mejores medidas para cada proceso.

- Agregar un
  [try-catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-us/library/0yd65esw(v=vs.80).aspx)
  para manejar la excepciones.
- Evitar colocar nombres demasiados abstractos a las variables y los
  elementos. Por ejemplo reemplazar 'ccliente' por 'clienteCedula' o
  'cedulaCliente' etc..
- Respetar la tabulacion en el código. Es muy importante tratar de
  mantener un código limpio y claro. De este modo te resultara mas
  fácil encontrar los errores y entender códigos mas complejos
  rápidamente.
- Yo acostumbro usar `ExecuteNonQuery()` devuelve solo el número de
  filas afectadas por una inserción, actualización o eliminación.
  Puedes utilizarlo para saber si se realizó la actualización
  correctamente.

Te dejo el código respetando tus condiciones en la consulta, pero realizando algunas otras mejoras como las mencionadas.
Debes reemplazar los valores asignados a los parámetros para las condiciones. Yo no sabia de donde los sacabas, ya que estabas usando los mismo que asignabas.

```
using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(
  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadenaconexion1"].ConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        conexion.Open();      

        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conexion;
        cmd.CommandText = "update cliente set telefono = @telefono, cedula = @cedula, nombre = @nombre, direccion = @direccion where cedula =  @cedulaWhere and nombre = @nombreWhere and telefono = @telefonoWhere and direccion = @direccionWhere";

        //Vamos a agregar los valores como parámetros para evitar la concatenación en la consulta.
        //Valores con los que se van a actualizar los campos
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cedula",ccliente.text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", ncliente.text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", ctelefono.text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", cdireccion.text)
        //Valores para las condiciones.
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cedulaWhere",'123456789');
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombreWhere", 'Luis Ocampo');
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefonoWhere", '3116085275');
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccionWhere", 'sddferr');

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // Ahora en result tenemos la cantidad de filas afectadas. 
       // En base a eso podemos determinar si hubo exito al realizar la actualizacion. En ese caso deberia ser > 0 por ej.

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    { 
        // aquí puedes manejar las excepciones. Mostrarlas al usuario o lo que desees.
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu código también tiene varios errores.

Comment: No lo dudo! solo le estaba remarcando las cosas básicas que yo se. Mas allá de eso, ese no seria mi código. Solo hice simples modificaciones al suyo. De todos modos siéntete en la liberad de agregar o corregir lo que desees en la respuesta. O bien crear una nueva. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Estás asignando un texto *SQL* al comando, pero no lo envías nunca al motor de base de datos.

Para enviar el `update`, ejecuta el método [ExecuteNonQuery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.7.2), por ejemplo:

```
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

**Advertencia**

De la manera que construyes tu sentencia, concatenando valores introducidos por el usuario, tu aplicación es vulnerable a ataques de [*inyección de SQL*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Investiga sobre el envío de sentencias parametrizadas a la base de datos para evitar este problema.

Comment: Buenos días, amigo el codigo me esta dando un error pero no se como corregirlo, int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
return result;
} en esta parte me dice que el return no debe ir seguido de una expresion de objeto, le quito el result y se quita el error.

Comment: Tu metodo devuelve algo? no mostraste la firma del mismo. @EdwardSc

Comment: Soy yo o es casi una copia de la otra respuesta? 

Comment: ¿copia? ¿quieres decir que no la escribí yo?

Comment: @Luis, si haces _hover_ sobre la etiqueta dónde dice "respondida hace xxxx", te muestra la hora exacta de la respuesta. Por fortuna, para mí, podrás ver que mi respuesta fue publicada a las `05:30:07Z` mientras que _la otra_ fue emitida 12 minutos después, a las `05:42:41Z`. De verdad me molesta que sugieras que estoy cometiendo un plagio, y menos en algo tan trivial como una respuesta aquí en SO.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIq3N.png

Comment: Solo dije que se parecía mucho, si tu escribiste antes, entonces disculpa, en ese caso solo se parecen ambas respuestas. Realmente no me afecta si hubo o no plagio, pero no negeras que hay mucha similitud, igual y es coincidencia.

Comment: No dijiste que se parecía, dijiste que es _casi una copia_ de la otra respuesta. Creo que es un comentario irresponsable.